# How to remove the file preview / minimap on the right side of the editor in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is very distracting to me:

[image: Screenshot code view in VS Code. On the right hand side is a very narrow column containing a small version of the code in the main view. There is a red arrow pointing to it, indicating that this is what the OP wants removed.]

I searched through the menus, but didn't find any setting to remove it. Is there any way to banish it from the editor?

Comment: It's called minimap. As of version 1.23.1 you can toggle minimap by menu View > Toggle Minimap

Comment: Also I keep accidentally clicking it, which jumps me to a different place in my code. Irritating.

Comment: At least one great thing about VS Code is we can remove irritating features like this one

Answer (score 696, accepted):

This is called [the minimap](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_minimap), and, as stated in that link,

> If you would like to disable minimap, you can set `"editor.minimap.enabled": false` in your user or workspace settings.

Once you save the settings file, the minimap will be gone.

Comment: This should really be a option in the View menu.

Comment: Nice work Microsoft!  This is an option now in the view menu :)

Comment: I wonder why the scaling is limited to a maximum of 3. I have a 27" 4K display, thus lots of space for some nice preview, but even with the maximum scale factor it occupies <10% of the editor's width.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not a fan of clutter and it is so much nicer now that it's gone

Comment: there should be a way in the top answer how to fix this with the Command Palette.

Answer (score 143):

You can also toggle the minimap from the Command Palette. You can go to 'View' and select Command Palette or just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type in the word 'minimap', you will instantly get the option to toggle the minimap.

[image: minimap toggle option]

Comment: This is the easiest one. Thank you.

Answer (score 55):

Click on "File" -> "Preferences" -> "Settings"
After Settings open, in "search settings" or press "Ctrl+f" type "editor.minimap.enabled" this will take you direct to the settings. On left of it edited option will be available right click to it. And set it to "false"
After wards you can see the right side pane is hide.

Answer (score 25):

Ctrl + Shift + P write Toggle minimap and hit enter and it's gone.

Answer (score 22):

While all the answers here will accomplish what the original question asks, they are showing a dated, manual way of hiding the minimap.  Current versions of Code have a "Toggle Minimap" item in the View menu, which will hide the minimap without the need to edit anything manually in User Settings.

Comment: You can get there pretty fast by using: F1 and type Toogle Minimap

Answer (score 18):

That view is called Minimap. To toggle, goto:

```
Toolbar -> View -> Toggle Minimap
```

Answer (score 17):

In VS,
Click on View on the top toolbar,
Then you will get a pop up, unselect --- Show minimap

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I know of 3 ways to show/hide it.

1. View -> Show Minimap
2. Ctrl+Shift+P -> Toggle Minimap
3. Settings.json -> "editor.minimap.enabled": false

I also made a Youtube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIpXWD2FJns) demonstrating all three ways.

Answer (score 15):

Oowekyala's answer is correct. I am adding a description with image for better understanding. Here is the number from 1 to 5 that describe the steps. Firstly click on File->Preferences->Settings. Then you will get User Setting page. Next, type "editor.minimap.enabled" in the search box(step-4). you will get setting option. On left of it edited option(step-5) will be available right click to it.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Go to **Preferences**->**Settings** Under text-editor dropdown go to Minimap and there uncheck the enable of a minimap.

Answer (score 13):

This thing is called minimap

to toggle is on and off

```
crtl+p
then search for ">minimap"
then just click enter
```

And if you again want to use it, **repeat** above step's again

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: `ctrl + shift + P` if you have atom keymap (or regular vscode?)

Answer (score 11):

Simply Click `F1` a text box will appear search for minimap 
and select View:Toggle MiniMap

Comment: I use Ctel+Shift+P only, this F1 + toggle minimap is even simpler,. Great, thanks Ali.

Comment: ctrl+shift+p or F1 both open Preferences, You Welcome

Answer (score 11):

**2022 Update**

The latest 2022 version of `VS Code` (1.73.0) now makes this even more simpler. Simply do the following to remove the minimap:

- Right click anywhere on the minimap and toggle the `Minimap` option.
- To reactivate the minimap, right click anywhere on the scroll bar and toggle the `Minimap` option.

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Easy to forget though since it's unexpected yet logical. Happened to me. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

From the View menuitem in Visual Code main menu, click on Toggle Minimap

On Windows.

Visual Code version 1.20.1

Comment: This is the same on Mac as well.

Answer (score 4):

On Mac: Code - Preferences - Settings, and in the right panel add the following line:

```
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false
```

Please care the commas, this file needs them after each but the last line. (It will warn you if a comma is missing.)

Comment: On Katalin it's as easy as clicking: View -> Show Minimap

Answer (score 0):

Launch your VSCode editor.
Go to the “File” menu.
Click the “Preferences” button.
Select “Settings.”
Look for the “Minimap” option and uncheck the “Controls Whether the Minimap is Shown”.

Answer (score -2):

Tools -> option ->Text Editor -> All Languages -> Scroll Bars -> Behavior
toggle between the 2 options (use bar mode .. & use Map mode ... ) given that "Show vertical scrollbar " option is checked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNiyK.png)

Comment: That is not a VS code dialog, IIRC.