# Remove code preview panel / minimap in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

On bigger monitors, I am going to experiment with using the integrated terminal on the right side instead of at the bottom, as pictured:

[image]

My question is, how can I remove the preview/overview panel here:

[image]

Apologies on the Rorschach test implicit in the question.

Comment: If you know the name of the panel, that would be a good start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the file preview on the right side of the editor in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774709/removing-the-file-preview-on-the-right-side-of-the-editor-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the [minimap](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_minimap-outline-view)

Disable it by [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings): `"editor.minimap.enabled": false`