# Anyway to get rid of this view in VSCode IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There's a little column to the right of your code window which shows all of your code at a huge glance. It's kinda handy to click to jump to a certain portion if you have a large file....ultimately, especially when I have 2 windows side by side, it takes up a lot of useful space. Anyways I can remove this? (Having a hard time researching it because I don't even know what it's called)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay...I tried some different search terms and found this article.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44774811/8887398

It's called "**minimap**".
[image]