# How to remove the extra space at the right side of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been trying to get the old default view window in order to edit code.

[image: VS Screen]

How can I remove this extra space marked in red?

Comment: Are you referring to the [minimap](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_minimap)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing the file preview on the right side of the editor in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774709/removing-the-file-preview-on-the-right-side-of-the-editor-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Click1: <kbd>Menu</kbd>

Click2: <kbd>View</kbd>

Click3: <kbd>Appearance</kbd>

Click4: <kbd>Centered Layout</kbd>

Untick: `Show Minimap`

Comment: Hey that works thnx

Answer (score 0):

It's called a Minimap and you can disable it under View > Show Minimap